# Stanford NLP - invalid character constants

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I created a project in Eclipse, imported the packages contained in `stanford-corenlp-3.6.0.jar` and after adding the required JARs I got a few errors, all of which are "Invalid character constants". Any approaches to fix this? I'm only analyzing English text. The errors were in the following files:

- `ChineseUtils.java` line 366
- `Sentence.java` line 109
- `State.java` line 180
- `WordShapeClassifier.java` line 511

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stanford NLP source code uses non-ASCII Unicode characters. You need to set up Eclipse or just this project so that it is expecting UTF-8 source code.  Here are [some instructions](http://stijndewitt.com/2010/05/05/unicode-utf-8-in-eclipse-java/).